# Flex 3 css style on a mx:panel

Tags: css, apache-flex, flex3, styling

I am trying to override the default panel  style on Flex 3.
And the following doesn't work.

```
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" 
layout="absolute" minWidth="955" minHeight="600"              
            creationComplete="init();">


 <mx:Style>
    .panel {
        borderAlpha: 1;
        borderColor: white;
    }
</mx:Style>
```

I got the style properties via here:
http://www.loscavio.com/downloads/blog/flex3_css_list/flex3_css_list.htm#Panel

Please kindly help.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your identifier is wrong, try using 'Panel' instead of '.panel'.

Answer (score 2):

The style should be Panel{...} instead of ".panel"

```
<mx:Style>
Panel {
    borderAlpha: 1;
    borderColor: white;
}
```